# Connect Client's Sandbox to different companies' Environment Hub?

Tags: sandbox, single-sign-on

While it may not be recommended, is there any way to add a client's sandbox environment to a different companies' environment hub ?  It would seem to provide an easy means for to SSO from the company org into the client's sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible with the Environment Hub.  SSO can be configured to work between any two orgs, even a sandbox and an unrelated production org.